# Flex builder - unable to introduce breakpoints

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, breakpoints

I am unable to introduce breakpoints in my flex debugger as mentioned in the image. Actually it says that "*Breakpoint cannot be set here because there is no executable code at this line*" but according to my knowledge everything is fine.
Have i done anything wrong, please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: have you changed the code while debugging ? If you were still in debug mode then this happens to me all the time, all I have to do is to stop debugging and try to re set the breakpoints, then it works.

Comment: I guess, compiled swf code does not match the code on your screenshots. Compile it again and ensure, that you're running it

Comment: I tried resetting the breakpoints but the problem exist still.

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking Project -> Clean. Sometimes something gets hung up and that fixes it in many cases for me.

Comment: If I stop debugging the project it becomes a valid breakpoint.. If I run the debugger it becomes invalid again. I even cleaned it before debugging again. Kindly help me.

Comment: Another thing you can try (though I personally haven't seen a debugger get this confused) is to run eclipse -clean (assuming you're running the plugin version of flash builder) to clean up possibly corrupted workspace metadata.  If this doesn't help, try re-importing your project into a fresh workspace.  I have sometimes had success fixing strange eclipse/flashbuilder issues with one of these two methods.

Comment: I am using a Flex builder 2.0.
I have tried to clean both Flex builder and Eclipse.
I have also tried to re-import the flex workspace.

But still this issue is not solved.
Even my team mate s facing the same problem in his machine.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing a breakpoint in your code but the code is not yet built ,therefore the code that you want to put a breakpoint is not at all present in the previously built SWF files. Rebuild your application and make sure that the new SWF is generated by checking the timestamp . Hope this helps 
Thanks !!